# Cancel touches if it moves out CGPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

I have a 400x400 `UIViewController`(lets call it ViewB) in center of my `RootController`. Inside the `ViewB` I have few `UIButton` (Customised `UIButton` Class with touch `UIResponder` methods).

I'm able to move the buttons around, but when the touch goes out of the ViewB, the button does cancel the touch!

What I really want is to totally cancel the touch and leave the button near the edge of `ViewB`.

Comment: How you moving buttons? you can set MIN and MAX point to the button and limit it inside the `ViewB` boundary.

Comment: you need to detect touches on ViewB's superView, and move the button from there

Comment: @Akhilrajtr: Does that mean, I have to check the Min & Max on touch moved method?
something like this :

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
float x = self.frame.origin.x;
    float y = self.frame.origin.y;
    
    if (x<10 || y<30 || y>438) {
//Cancel Touch
    }
}

Comment: @Basheer_CAD : I understand what you mean, But the app was developed like this and all touches are handled within the UIButton objects.

Comment: @Danialzo can you show the code in `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    ....
    CGRect viewBFrame = ViewB.view.frame;
    CGRect buttonToRect = //calculated button frame
    CGPoint buttonOrigin = buttonToRect.origin;
    CGFloat xMax = CGRectGetWidth(viewBFrame) - CGRectGetWidth(buttonToRect);
    CGFloat yMax = CGRectGetHeight(viewBFrame) - CGRectGetHeight(buttonToRect);
    buttonOrigin.x = MAX(0, buttonOrigin.x);
    buttonOrigin.x = MIN(xMax, buttonOrigin.x);

    buttonOrigin.y = MAX(0, buttonOrigin.y);
    buttonOrigin.y = MIN(yMax, buttonOrigin.y);

    //set buttonToRect to Button

}
```

Note : Assuming button is subView of `ViewB`